# Update text of column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, edit

I have created table as

```
create table tab (id int, mytext varchar(200));
```

Now I inserted values as

```
insert into tab values
(1, 'text 11,text 12,'),
(2, 'text 21,text 22,'),
(3, 'text 31,text 32,'),
(4, 'text 41,text 42,');
```

Now what I wanted to do is add text `text none,` at the start of the text. For that I had to execute query as

```
update tab set mytext = concat('text none,', mytext)
```

However, mistakenly I executed the query as:

```
update tab set mytext = concat('text none', mytext)
```

I missed the COMMA (,) after 'none'.

Now I have data as

```
1   textnonetext 11,text 12,
2   textnonetext 21,text 22,
3   textnonetext 31,text 32,
4   textnonetext 41,text 42,
```

What I want is change above output to:

```
1   textnone,text 11,text 12,
2   textnone,text 21,text 22,
3   textnone,text 31,text 32,
4   textnone,text 41,text 42,
```

i.e. add comma(,) after none.

Any idea how to get this done?

### [SQL Fiddle for testing](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8b28/1)

**Note :** The length of the original data in the `mytext` fields is not fixed; for some ids it's 6, for some it's 50.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one,

```
update tab 
set mytext = concat('text none, ', Replace(mytext, 'text none',''));
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b7e9/2)

or simply do replace if you don't have any special reason to use concat

```
update tab 
set mytext = Replace(mytext, 'text none','text none, ');
```

Answer (score 2):

Or simply use [replace](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) without using concat as well:

```
UPDATE tab
SET mytext = REPLACE(mytext, 'text none', 'text none,')
```